# Create a Excel Matrix using column data from DB table?

Tags: database, excel, oracle

I have a criteria where I have data in the following format.

This is

## Sheet 1:Column Data from Table

```
ID    | Column A| Column B | Column C
1     | Value A | Value X  | Answer 1
2     | Value A | Value Y  | Answer 2
3     | Value A | Value Z  | Answer 3
4     | Value B | Value X  | Answer 4
5     | Value B | Value Y  | Answer 5
6     | Value B | Value Z  | Answer 6
7     | Value C | Value X  | Answer 7
8     | Value C | Value Y  | Answer 8
9     | Value C | Value Z  | Answer 9
...
```

## Sheet 1: Target as Matrix

```
          Value X | Value Y | Value Z 
Value A |Answer 1 |Answer 2 |Answer 3
Value B |Answer 4 |Answer 5 |Answer 6
Value C |Answer 7 |Answer 8 |Answer 9
```

**From Sheet 1:**

- For each entry column A, there is a repeating set of entries in column B
- The values in column B are the same for every value of column A.
- The lookup of column A1 and B1 gives the value I need from C1.

I have tried to use vlookups and offsets but they do not provide the answer I am looking for.

Can anyone please provide a way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a real excel output file with that format or you just want the output of a query with that format?

Comment: Should it be a single `query` or there in no restriction to build the result with a `function` or `procedure`?

Comment: Hello, the format specified is derived from a query join between 3 tables where they are as follows; a main table having column A, second table having column B; third table that is the child containing column A and Column B as foreign keys and having value for Column C for each combination. Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you actually need an excel file?